# Develop a window’s service in c# for backing up data from 4 different locations to one location?

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, service, filesystemwatcher

Requirement: The service should monitor 4 different systems and as and when a new file is created on any of these systems, the file should be moved to a server location.  Moving need not be an immediate priority but eventually have to move it. These system generate files in bulk (30+ files /system/min), while sometimes the systems are just idle. So there is no fix time for file generation.  Also the service should have a user interface so the configuration would be set by the user.

Initial thought: The service would be installed on the server location. The service will monitor 4 different folders on these 4 systems. Monitoring will be done by using “FileSystemWatcher” on these folders. The files will be moved to a folder located on the server.

Any suggestion is appreciated or a possible different approach to work on this problem?

Comment: Rsync might be something to look at.

Comment: Also watch out for so many files being created/deleted that it causes the watcher to not be able to report them all...

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887623). This is essentially what you want to do is keep all your files synchronized to a central endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the FileSystemWatcher that .net offers 
you could also monitor a fileshare
you could create a process that makes an entry and then post the results into a Database and then from there do your processing.. 
lots of ways you can skin this cat.. 
You could create a WMI process that runs off a cmd or batch file process or even a C# process could do that as well..